# Catch exceptions in CherryPy 3.2 during body.process

Tags: cherrypy, turbogears

I got the following error in a live site where a utf character (test string 'Îñţérñâţîöñåļîžæ†îøñ') was submitted:

```
400 Bad Request

The request entity could not be decoded. The following charsets were attempted: ['utf-8']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 648, in respond
    self.body.process()
  File ".virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpreqbody.py", line 931, in process
    super(RequestBody, self).process()
  File ".virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpreqbody.py", line 500, in process
    proc(self)
  File ".virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpreqbody.py", line 153, in process_urlencoded
    "charsets were attempted: %s" % repr(entity.attempt_charsets))
HTTPError: (400, "The request entity could not be decoded. The following charsets were attempted: ['utf-8']")
Powered by CherryPy 3.2.0
```

I can fix this using `<form type="POST" accept-charset="utf-16">`.

Normally, I catch errors in application code and log them or email them to myself, but this error never reached my application code which runs on TurboGears 1.5.

Any idea on how I can hook in to catch and log errors generated by CherryPy, and secondarily, give the user a better 404 page?

---

The method of error handling listed at [_cperror.html#unanticipated-errors](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/_cperror.html?highlight=error_response#unanticipated-errors)
 doesn't work for this sort of error (but kicks in on e.g. static file missing)

Comment: I've added a pull request: https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/pull-request/93/add-error-handling-hook-to-http-400